# Stored Procedures in Python for PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

we are still pretty new to Postgres and came from Microsoft Sql Server.

We are wanting to write some stored procedures now. Well, after struggling to get something more complicated than a `hello world` to work in pl/pgsql, we decided it's better if we are going to learn a new language we might as well learn Python because we got the same query working in it in about 15 minutes(note, none of us actually know python).

So I have some questions about it in comparison to pl/psql.

1. Is pl/Pythonu slower than pl/pgsql?
2. Is there any kind of "good" reference for how to write good stored procedures using it? Five short pages in the Postgres documentation doesn't really tell us enough.
3. What about query preparation? Should it always be used?
4. If we use the SD and GD arrays for a lot of query plans, will it ever get too full or have a negative impact on the server? Will it automatically delete old values if it gets too full?
5. Is there any hope of it becoming a trusted language?

Also, our stored procedure usage is extremely light. Right now we only have 4, but we are still trying to convert little bits of code over from Sql Server specific syntax(such as variables, which can't be used in Postgres outside of stored procedures)

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to write stored procedures?  Why not write ordinary applications in Python and use the database as an ordinary data store?

Comment: Because we have over 10,000 lines of C# code written already. And there are some things where if we did it completely in the application would require 3 or more round trips to the DB server, so we would prefer to just have 1 round trip and the DB server do a tiny extra bit of processing

Comment: @earlz: Please update your question with additional facts.  Please do not comment on your own question.  It's your question.  Make it complete, please, so others can learn from it, also.

Comment: @earlz: Rather than use stored procedures to reduce round-trips, fetch more rows and do more processing outside the database.  You'll find that it's usually far, far faster than a stored procedure.  Stored procedures are not a virtue -- they're often a maintenance nightmare.  Why work so hard?

Comment: Although this is irrelevant since this will be for a website which will be on a LAN with the DB Server, if this was a client-server thing, this wouldn't work. Imagine grabbing "just a few extra rows" on a 15kbs satellite connection.

Comment: @earlz: I'm not sure I get a 15KBS satellite connection and a RDBMS.  That seems doomed from the outset.  But, I've found that the application program processing is often faster than RDBMS processing and fetching too many rows is usually faster than having a stored procedure try to do the work.  Hence my question.  If it's so hard, why are you pursuing it?  Do you have hard evidence that this is the best approach?

Comment: Do you have any hard evidence that I shouldn't use Stored Procedures? This is all irrelevant. I'm not asking if I *should* use stored procedures. And you have no idea how our application works, so how can you judge if stored procedures are bad for it?

Comment: @earlz: Yes, actually, I do have lots of hard evidence that stored procedures have become a maintenance nightmare and perform generally quite poorly.  That's why I was *asking* why you were trying so hard to do them in Python.  If you're simply set on using them, then press on.  I don't have an answer.  I'm *asking* why this is so important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Depends on what operations you're doing.
2. Well, combine that with a general Python documentation, and that's about what you have.
3. No. Again, depends on what you're doing. If you're only going to run a query once, no point in preparing it separately.
4. If you are using persistent connections, it might. But they get cleared out whenever a connection is closed.
5. Not likely. Sandboxing is broken in Python and AFAIK nobody is really interested in fixing it. I heard someone say that python-on-parrot may be the most viable way, once we have pl/parrot (which we don't yet).

Bottom line though - if your stored procedures are going to do database work, use pl/pgsql. Only use pl/python if you are going to do non-database stuff, such as talking to external libraries.